# Как правильно распарсить JSON на Python?

Tags: python, json, парсер, api

В ответе от api yandex получаю словарь JSON. Не знаю как правильно распарсить строку `user_id` чтобы получить фамилии и инициалы сотрудников. Подскажите как можно это реализовать?

**JSON**:

```
    {'last_closed_at': '2023-01-31T10:18:20.169000',
    'orders': [{'closed_at': '2023-01-31T13:18:20.169000+03:00',
    'created_at': '2023-01-31T13:17:18.984000+03:00',
    'final_price': '1489.2',
    'fuel_type': 'a95_premium',
    'liters_filled': '30.0',
    'station_location': [52.238352, 52.790106],
    'user_id': '89543ef5c3784889ab10129ef1257768'}]}
```

**Код моего запроса**:

```
import requests import json url = 'b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/orders/…’ headers = {'Authorization': Bearer токен'} response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers) print(response.json())
```

Comment: Вот код моего запроса:             import requests
import json


url = 'https://b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/orders/tanker?since_datetime=2022-05-12T13:32:49.123&since_datetime=2022-05-15T06:11:52.834’
headers = {'Authorization': Bearer токен'}
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())

Comment: `response.json().get('user_id')`. Когда вы вызываете метод `json()` вы получаете десериализованные данные, а значит на выходе у вас есть `dict`, у которого можете уже получить информацию по ключу

Comment: код запроса поместите в вопрос. зачем он в комментарии?

Comment: print(response.json().get(‘user_id’)) возвращает None. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Возможно что в json стоит кодировка? Если так то как получить значение ключа user_id на русском языке?

Comment: @Elena распечатайте респонс без json, убедитесь что он не пустой.

Comment: print(response.text) выдает тот же самый ответ  {'last_closed_at': '2023-01-31T10:18:20.169000',
    'orders': [{'closed_at': '2023-01-31T13:18:20.169000+03:00',
    'created_at': '2023-01-31T13:17:18.984000+03:00',
    'final_price': '1489.2',
    'fuel_type': 'a95_premium',
    'liters_filled': '30.0',
    'station_location': [52.238352, 52.790106],
    'user_id': '89543ef5c3784889ab10129ef1257768'